# Turbolinks, On destroy event - Ruby on rails 5

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks, turbolinks-5

I would like to know if there is an event that is called when a page is destroyed/changed. For example i'm in `localhost:3000` and i would like to navigate to `localhost:3000/articles` but before that i need to destroy some javascripts components, so i was wondering if there is a way to have something like

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:before-destroy', function() {});
```

Or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved. I found the list of events for turbolinks: github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#full-list-of-events. The one i was looking for is turbolinks:before-visit